# Why is /usr/bin/arch not installed?

Tags: macos, terminal

My application has been depending on the presence of `/usr/bin/arch`, and it was my understanding that this was part of the standard Mac OS X installation. It's there if I install Snow Leopard from the DVD, without installing the developer tools. However, I've now encountered two users with 10.6.7 who are missing this file. Is there a normal way of getting Mac OS X that omits `arch`? Or do these users' installations just happen to be broken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/usr/bin/arch` is part of the com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem package, so it should be present in every stock Mac OS X installation. Running:

```
$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/arch
```

will tell you the package that installed `/usr/bin/arch`, and running:

```
$ pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem
```

will tell you the contents of that package.

It might be worth it to run the latter in the machines of those users that haven’t got `arch`.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem` shows that for one of these users the package did not contain `arch`.

Comment: @Michael Do you know whether those are Macs or Hackintoshes? It’s odd not to have `arch` or it not being listed in com.apple.pkg.BaseSystem.

Comment: Both are real Macs: a 2010 MacBook Pro and an early 2009 Mac Pro.

Comment: I up-voted this answer, but I haven't accepted yet because I'm still hoping that someone will know what could cause this problem.

Comment: @Michael You might want to ask this on http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this file would be missing, but `uname -p` prints the processor architecture name. Check `man uname` for other variables.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `arch` to execute a command using a given architecture, not to determine the current architecture. I suppose I could use `posix_spawn()` for this, but really my question is about whether it's normal for `arch` to be missing.

Comment: @Michael Ah I see, In this case, is it in `/bin/arch`, and if not, what's the output of `uname -a` on the user's machine just to see if there's anything odd about the system

Comment: `uname` doesn’t output the processor architecture. It outputs the kernel architecture instead. In an Intel, 64-bit capable machine running a 32-bit kernel, `uname` outputs i386.

Comment: Why not looking at "/proc/cpuinfo"? (this is what the kernel reports, but this may be a virtualized view when running in a VM, where the hypervisor may be configured to hide some details, reduce the capabilities, or emulate some)

Comment: And if you want even more details, there is /proc/kmsg (which keeps a part of the kernel boot logs with advanced CPU info, configuration and compatiblity tests), but its read access is restricted to root.